# Activity layout completely messed up?

Tags: java, android, xml

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.BetterViewPager
        android:id="@+id/signupViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/signUpCircleIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:ci_drawable="@drawable/indicator_selected"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    viewPager.setAdapter(new SignUpPagesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    circleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Has anyone had the same problem? It's not the first time that it's happening, it happened a long time ago and I have no idea how I fixed it, but I'm also looking for the reason behind this.

**Edit - quick fix**
If you're running into the same problem, I fixed it by setting a background color to the layout, but I'm still curious of why this happens.

Comment: Can you verify it is reproducable with ordinary `ViewPager` instead of `BetterViewPager`?

Comment: Yes, also reproducible with just an empty layout, and empty onCreate